# Modal dialog form not in the center of parent when application tiled

Tags: c#

I have a small app that requests user input ever couple of minutes. The app produces a modal pop up and waits for the user input but when the app is tiled with other programs the dialog appears randomly in different locations on the screen.

I've set the position in the constructor to CenterParent, and it doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you set the Form used as a Dialog's ShowInTaskBar = false : I can still reproduce the out-of-whack positioning of the Dialog : launch your application (with a few other windows open) : before first dialog appears, context-click on TaskBar : choose 'Show Windows Side by Side' If you are speaking of setting your main Form's 'ShowInTaskBar = false : that's a "hack," not a "solution," and it violates standard windows forms ui programming guidelines which exist for good reasons. If you want to see another solution, just let me know; if you are happy with the current technique : great :)

Comment: I don't think he meant the main form, but the child form that needed to be centered. Reordering windows by clicking Cascade should (in the asker's opinion) not reorder the child window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have forgotten to set the parent correctly in the Show command? It should be set to the form that you want it to center with.

```
yourFormInstance.Show(parentForm);
```

EDIT: asker came with solution. He meant that clicking Tile Windows reorganizes windows, including his one (after it was already shown). The solution: `myForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;`.

Comment: Aha, you meant: after Tiling is selected, all windows are reorganized. I thought you meant: tile, then open your window. But indeed: tiling is a function of Windows that you have no control over, unless you are just not there (i.e., invisible to the task bar)

Comment: Abel wrote : "tiling is a function of Windows that you have no control over" : true in the sense an end-user can do anything at any time, but, more imporantly, FOR THE PROGRAMMER, the changing of the Window location and size produced by a user's choice of a tiling option from the TaskBar DOES trigger the SizeChanged and LocationChanged Events of a Form which a programmer CAN write Event Handlers for and deal with as needed.

Comment: @BillW: very true so! But as you say: you have to implement that functionality, it's not part of the available properties.